# can't type lower cased e in amazon ec2 (Amazon Linux)

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, bash, sh

After a few days of operation on my new ec2 build, the following happens:

1. I log into SSH, everything is fine, I do my coding
2. I return the next day, and log into SSH
3. I cannot type a lower cased `e` anymore--I get the error ding when I type it
4. I try to ssh from a different computer, same problem
5. I reboot the server, same problem
6. I open `nano` or `vi` and `e` works fine, just not in `bash` or `sh`
7. I terminate the server, create a new one, install from scratch, a few days later it happens again

This is baffling! Where do I even start to troubleshoot?

My Local Machine Setup(s):

- windows XP or 7
- putty (latest) or cygwin/openssh

The EC2 setup

- Amazon Linux (default options)
- node.js
- iptables forwarding port 80 to node on port 8003
- emacs, npm, and openssl-devel
- no other mods
- [Here is my /etc/profile](http://pastebin.com/s6A37Vxx)
- [Here is my /etc/inputrc](http://pastebin.com/8bMkEp3b)
- [Here is my ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile](http://pastebin.com/uSEM6m7X)
- [output of env](http://pastebin.com/15HXSb7i)

Output of `stty -a` while I can't type an `e`

```
sh-4.1$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 30; columns 95; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts -cdtrdsr
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany
-imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

In case it helps someone else with a similar issue, I created a script (called `sub`) to convert upper-cased E to lower-cased, then echo the command back. Then I run it in backticks to get an `e` on the command line::

```
#!/bin/sh
echo ${@//E/e}

> `sub Emacs /Etc/profilE`
```

**UPDATES**

1. This breaks for all users
2. In bash only (csh works fine)
3. In emacs edit mode only

I've created [a chat room to discuss this issue](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1879/discuss-se-question-about-e-in-ssh) and hone in the solution.

Comment: post the output of `stty -a` on the ec2 server when it goes wonky

Comment: done; thanks for the suggestion (although I have no idea what to make of it ;) )

Comment: Is there anything funny in /etc/profile, ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc ?

Can you su to another user and try it? It seems either that or maybe your keyboard character map was changed - possibly during updates?

Comment: I did a `sudo su -` with no joy; I posted /etc/profile online for review: http://pastebin.com/s6A37Vxx

Comment: Also, please post your comments as answers; the question is how to troubleshoot and these are some great solutions ;)

Comment: @Kato "How to troubleshoot" is not a valid Question on [sf] so we've taken to it mean "How do I fix $PROBLEM". A minor detail, but covered in the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I guess I disagree; the FAQ says it's not for "general computer troubleshooting"; it's a very specific problem that I'm trying to troubleshoot and with any luck, solve here for others; I already know nobody has the specific answer though (because Google doesn't ;) )

Comment: If you run `reset` followed by `stty sane` does the problem go away?

Comment: @voretaq7 - no, but I'm not exactly sure what it means to run those from a script (obviously I can't run them from the CLI since they contain `e` :(  Is there anything needed in my script to say "this applies to my shell session"?

Comment: Also look in `~/.inputrc` and `/etc/inputrc` for broken readline keybindings.

Comment: @Kato: copy and paste `reset; stty sane`

Comment: @lain - oh I so wish! copy/paste strips the `e` chars :(

Comment: @Sergey_Vlasov I've linked to all of the appropriate configs in the original post ;)

Comment: I've created [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1879/discuss-se-question-about-e-in-ssh), if you would like to offer additional suggestions or have a quick conversation; thanks, in advance for all ideas!

Comment: Phew, that was a subtle one; many thanks to MikeyB, Zoredache, @voretaq7, and rovanju for all the troubleshooting help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You've mistakenly put:

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/emacs
```

into your `/etc/inputrc`. This will map the letter 'e' to nothing at all.

Remove that and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks so much for the assist! Got to remember not to let people program while I'm out drinking ;(

Comment: Can someone explain why setting an environment variable breaks the letter 'e'?

Comment: `/etc/inputrc` is NOT for environment variables. It's a specific input format read by readline.