# Can't enter the letter 'e' over ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, terminal

Right now I am experiencing some very, very weird behaviour on a Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS server I am managing.

Connecting to the server over ssh either from cygwin(mintty) or a terminal on a Linux machine, I can't type the letter `e`.

I have done the following debugging:

- The letter `e` can be typed in vim on the remote server
- The letter `e` can be typed in the terminal on the local machines
- `$TERM` is set to `xterm`
- `$LANG`, `$LANGUAGE` and `$LC_ALL` are set to `de_DE.utf8`
- `locale charmap` returns `UTF-8`

Right now, I am completely out of ideas what could be causing this.

I'd be very happy about some advice on how to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, @EricRenouf, this helped me solve the problem! Check my answer for details if you are interested.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

My problem is not the same as [can't type lower cased e in amazon ec2 (Amazon Linux)](https://serverfault.com/questions/335874/cant-type-lower-cased-e-in-amazon-ec2-amazon-linux), but similar.

After checking `/etc/inputrc` and finding nothing out of the ordinary, I remembered that I did do some keybinding in the `/etc/bash.bashrc`. This was already there for a very long time and worked flawlessly, though. Why would it make problems now?

I found out when I checked `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

As all files are managed using ansible, this command had been inserted using ansible as well:

```
- name: Up Arrow Command Search
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/bash.bashrc line="bind '\"\e[A\"':history-search-backward"

- name: Down Arrow Command Search
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/bash.bashrc line="bind '\"\e[B\"':history-search-forward"
```

Apparantly, a recent ansible update changed the behaviour of lineinfile, so that the command resulted in

```
bind \e[A:history-search-backward
bind \e[B:history-search-forward
```

instead of

```
bind '"\e[A"':history-search-backward
bind '"\e[B"':history-search-forward
```

And therefore resulted in the weird behaviour.

A big thanks goes to [Eric Renouf](https://serverfault.com/users/279471/eric-renouf), for his link to the other question with the similar problem!

Comment: This shouldn't only affect SSH, it should affect any terminal on the server.